Извлечь с Excel ячейки только то что в скобках
Всем привет! Подскажите пожалуйста кто знает функцию в excel, чтобы с ячейки оставить данные только те что в скобках, когда в ячейке, могут быть их несколько. Спасибо
Пример ячейки 1:

Комплектация В комплект поставки замка AL-250SM входят:

корпусная часть (1) 1 шт.
якорная часть (2) 1 шт.
прокладки 0,5мм (3) 4 шт.
прокладки 1мм (4) 8 шт.
планка декоративная (5) 2 шт.
пластина переходная (6) 4 шт.
винт М4х10 (7) 6 шт.
винт М5х10 (8) 8 шт.
диод 1N5406 1 шт.
магнитоконтактный извещатель ИО 102-15/1 1 шт.
руководство по эксплуатации 1 шт.
упаковочная коробка 1 шт

(215058)   Комплект для накладного монтажа   MK AL-250S   (белый)
(219561)   Комплект для накладного монтажа   MK AL-250S   (серый)
(220654)   Комплект для накладного монтажа   MK AL-250S   (коричневый)
(218951)   Комплект для монтажа на стеклянную дверь   MK AL-250 S
Glass (285542)   Комплект проставок замка для дверей с большим зазором
250SM (20-25)

Пример ячейки 2:

Особенности Эксплуатация внутри помещений, установить защитный диод
типа 1N4006 Комплектация Корпусная часть, якорная часть, основание для
крепления на стену, крепежные винты
(217900) L-уголок AL-50FC


Добавьте в вопрос примеры содержимого ячеек и желаемый результат

@SwaD извиняюсь, добавил.
